# SQLite calculate the avg of value with a 10 minute interval

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a huge dataset of sensor data that gets logged every 2 seconds to a SQLite database. I'm trying to get the passed 30 days of data; however I want to "group" it so it only grabs the data every 10 minutes instead of every single data point. and average all the values within that 10 minute window. My table look something like this:

```
sensor_values:
  - id
  - value // example value -> 13.22
  - created_at // timestamp
```

Pseudo SQL

```
select avg(value) from sensor_values where created_at >= date('now','-30 days') 
group by (created_at interval of 10 minutes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following may do what you wish :-

```
SELECT 
    avg(value)
FROM sensor_values 
WHERE created_at >= date('now','-30 days')
GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m%d%M',created_at) / 10
```